# Object files do not contain symbols that should be there

Tags: c++, com

This is the specific error I am getting:

```
libFoo.so: undefined reference to `IID_IFOOBAR'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/home/F.exe] Error 1
```

when I try to check the symbols in my object file A.o

```
nm A.obj | grep IID_
```

I get no symbols listed in my object file of the 'IID_IFOOBAR' that should be there since it is defined in a header file as:

```
extern const blahType IID_IFOOBAR
```

Am I missing something?  Should IID_IFOOBAR be defined differently somewhere since it is an extern variable?  If this question is too specific I will remove it.  But perhaps someone's intuition will help me here.

Comment: Look at the output of `nm -D`, `nm -g`, and `nm -u` and see how the output differs.

Comment: @greyfade, just tried it

nm -D : No Symbols
nm -g : lists other symbols but not the one I'm looking for
nm -u : lists "U" symbols, but not the one I'm looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EDIT]
Add the definition of the variable somewhere (without `extern`). Extern identifiers without initializers are not definitions - the definition must be somewhere else.

Comment: But there should also be one (and only one) defintion in a .c/.cpp file somewhere.

Comment: I shall accept this as the answer since it is right. I have found the problem. The definition needed to be in an unexpected place, so the extern can remain. Thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer a bit. The extern must be somewhere if you want to have external linkage, it's just that you need to have the definition also.

Comment: The `extern` keyword on a variable with an initialiser is _not_ ignored if the variable is also marked `const` since the `extern` in this case provides external linkage. Adding an initialiser in this case would have worked and satisfied the ODR. Of course the `extern` would then be pointless as the variable is defined everywhere that uses it. :)

Comment: Woops, I forgot about the fact the linker won't be happy about the multiple symbols _because_ it is marked extern.

Answer (score 1):

To make an `extern`ly *declared* symbol appear in your symbol table as "undefined", you should actually *use* it from within a library.

If your object file neither contains a *definition* of symbol (as opposed to declaration) nor uses it somewhere inside its functions, then the symbol won't appear in the symbol table.  Why should it?